# Blender 2.8 only renders the first frame of an animation

Tags: rendering

When I render an animation -a simple camera movement over the objects-, Blender 2.8 only renders the first frame continously. Problem repeates in Eevee and also in Cycles. I have checked the parameters and everything appears to be fine. It is getting me crazy.

[image]pg

Comment: Update: I am able to render by typing value '2' in the step when I define the frame start and end.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I had this issue too until a few minutes ago, now it got sorted. What worked for me is changing the composoting nodes. Basically making sure that everything ends up in the "composite" node and not just the "viewer" node.

A safer way I found is once I know how I want the result with the "viewer" node, just get rid of it and point the nodes to "composite"

I hope it helps.